# Is there any connection between the Gundam series?

Tags: gundam

I have watched a few (very few) gundam series, and to me they seem like independent mecha anime series.

Is there any connection between the Gundam series? Or are each of them in separate universes?

Comment: related http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7548/where-to-start-with-gundam

Comment: related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8715/what-is-the-chronology-of-the-gundam-series

Answer (score 1):

you have many gundam series with connections!
For example, Gundam 79, the first one, is in the same chronology line with Z, ZZ, stardust memory and others. this series are differents, but in the same line, in the same conflict (AEUG vs Zeon)

But, Gundam Wing, Seed, build Fighters...are differents.

You can follow this example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Many of the Gundam Series takes place in separate universes, which can be called timelines such as:

- Mobile Suit Gundam - UC timeline
- Mobile Suit Gundam 00 - AD timeline
- Mobile Suit Gundam Iron Blooded Orphans - PD timeline

However, there are several links between the mobile suit gundam universes in terms of plot like:

- Mobile Suit Gundam has a V shaped antenna
- Existence of evolved humans
- Mascot character - Haro

But other than those the story and characters are completely independent between the timelines.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there is no connection between them.
It basically means that you can watch each one indepent from the others, you basically won't miss out in relevant information to the given selection.

However they have familiarities. In each universe/timeline/planet/section whatever you want to call them, there is conflict going on. The gundams in the given era with the given pilot have plenty of technology and fighting skills common. But that is about it. Some have the same technology level so I guess they COULD take place in the same universe or maybe all do but with different timelines.

You can basicaly see each gundam series as a seperate anime with the "mecha" genre as common relation.